# Keys With same values in array

Tags: php, arrays

Once I was asked one question in an interview. Below is the question :

```
$arry= array("1"=>"20", "2"=>"20", "3"=>"30", "4"=>"40" "5"=>"20");
```

I was asked to find the keys which have the same value by using the foreach loop.

I still don't know the solution to this question. Any Help??

Comment: As interview questions go, that's about as basic as it gets. Where are you stuck with it? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$arry= array("1"=>"20", "2"=>"20", "3"=>"30", "4"=>"40", "5"=>"20");

$results = array(); 
foreach($arry as $key=>$value) {
    $results[$value][] = $key;
}

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$results[$value][]` issue a notice (`$results[$value]` is never declared as an array in your code). That's why I added the `array_fill_keys` call to my answer

Comment: Doesn't issue any notices for me with full error logging

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it should, but in this case I'd simply put a `@` in front of that line since it's known shorthand. @Mark you probably don't have `error_reporting(-1)` active.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem `$results[$value][]` is in writting because of `[]` so, even if `$value` is null; its not trigger any issue, while, if you echo `$results[$undefined];` you will see undefined index notice

Comment: Nearly envy your. Codes with php notice and late than my answer get so much votes. :(.

Comment: @srain - I still can't see any notices with E_ALL, clearly I'm too thick to understand this PHP stuff

Comment: @MarkBaker: Sorry, it seems I've kickstarted some form of discussion in the comments to your asnwer. I was just curious. I haven't tried your code, but I expected it to produce notices. If you say it doesn't, that's ok for me... I do wonder, though: wouldn't you _expect_ this to produce a notice? or am I massing some Zend engine wizardry here?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: Argh... the `@` suppressor of _death_! I hate that, don't use it... save for those few rare use-cases where you can't help a notice from being issued (seen this only 2 or 3 times in 10 years). If there's a notice, there's an issue, if there's an issue: don't ignore it _fix it_! (had to get that off of my chest)

Comment: I tested it, no notice with full logging. Sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update srain... I've just been backtracking through different versions of PHP to see if I can trigger an error with it; saves me going back prior to 5.2... and I agree with Elias about `@`

Comment: @MarkBaker: can you please help me with arrays..?? i really never understood them properly. these multidimensional and all. if you can.??

Comment: The easiest way to understand arrays is to read through all the phpdocs array [information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), [sorting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and [functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and experiment with each example, then ask __specific__ questions here about anything you don't understand

Comment: @MarkBaker: alright. i will be doing the same as you said.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the `@` operator is just as evil as `eval`, `goto` or any other language construct that is not **inherently** evil, just often abused. No reason not to use any of them **ever** when you do realize the consequences and consciously decide to do so.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: `eval` isn't inherently evil, of course. Nothing is. A gun isn't _inherently_ evil. Both of them are dangerous, though, and, IMHO, should be avoided as much as possible. In this case, you _can_ avoid it, so avoid it. I've mentioned a few use cases, well: use it there, but not if there's an alternative

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I totally agree none of those constructs should ever be used without really, really, really knowing why, my argument in this case (and the original reason to write it) is just that this specific code's behaviour can never become *undefined* because of it. The only error that could ever happen from that line is 'unknown index',  which is intended, and as thus a valid candidate for suppression to keep the code short and thus improve readability (and actually even performance, though that is premature micro-optimization ;)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: I get where you're comming from, but supressing a notice is actually going to reduce performance, [read this article](http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance). I've also tested this myself. an array `array('bar' => 'car');`, looping over it 1,000,000 times, and doing `$var = $foo['zar'];` to emulate typo: _0.91650390625"_ time taken. using `$var = isset($foo['zar']) ? $foo['zar'] : null;` using the `isset` _language construct_, the same loop takes _0.26469206809998_. The closest both got was <.3 for isset vs <.85 for `@`

Comment: Safe to say that using `isset` is not only cleaner, but _significantly_ faster (slowest `isset`: 0.27253603935242 vs fastest `@`: 0.83010315895081), more than 3 times faster.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this. PHP has always been a piece of smelly crap, but I thought that by now it would be safe to assume that a "never show notices" flag would be part of the actual execution context, and as such checked **before** instead of **after** a lot of performance is wasted on generating messages, debug data, call stacks etc. Chalk another one up on the board of [PHP WTFs](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/).

Answer (score 2):

## [See the result here](http://codepad.org/DYi0lqou)

```
<?php
$arry= array("1"=>"20", "2"=>"20", "3"=>"30", "4"=>"40","5"=>"20");

$list = array();
foreach ($arry as $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($list[$value]))
    {
        $list[$value] = array();
    }

    $list[$value][] = $key;
}
var_export($list);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arry= array("1"=>"20", "2"=>"20", "3"=>"30", "4"=>"40", "5"=>"20");
$newArr = array();
foreach($arry as $key => $val) {
    if(!array_key_exists($val, $newArr)) $newArr[$val] = "";
    $newArr[$val] .=  " - " . $key;
}

var_dump($newArr);
```

**OUTPUT** : `VALUES => KEYS_WITH_SAME_VALUES`

```
array (size=3)
20 => string ' - 1 - 2 - 5' (length=12)
30 => string ' - 3' (length=4)
40 => string ' - 4' (length=4)
```

Comment: Or, using Mark Baker's answer (or mine): `foreach($newArr as $keys){ implode(' - ', $keys); }`. Which will produce the same strings, except for improved formatting _"1 - 2 - 5"_ instead of _" - 1 - 2 - 5"_... :P

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arry as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value == $findValue)
        print $key.' ';
}
```

Example `$findValue` is 20, then this code print `1 2 5`

Comment: but icould be any number of values, i mean there can be many keys which would have same values.. not only 20...

Comment: can you please tell me about the variable $findValue.. ?? do i have to declare it as null?? or something. ?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way :

```
<?php
$array = array("1"=>"20", "2"=>"20", "3"=>"30", "4"=>"40" ,"5"=>"20");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

With foreach :

```
<?php
$array = array("1"=>"20", "2"=>"20", "3"=>"30", "4"=>"40" ,"5"=>"20");
$result = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $result[$value]++;
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Give it a try [here](http://phpfiddle.org/)